# Missing multipolygon after ImpOSM import to PostGIS

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, imposm

I've been testing ImpOSM 2.5.0 with an extract of Washington State (in the U.S.) and am very impressed with the overall result.  However, I noticed that fairly prominent lake was missing from the resulting "osm" DB, so I started to dig a bit deeper.  I confirmed that the lake is present in the extract, here are it's details:

```
    <relation id="411923" version="13">
            <member type="way" ref="42114354" role="inner"/>
            <member type="way" ref="42114348" role="inner"/>
            <member type="way" ref="42114344" role="inner"/>
            <member type="way" ref="42114346" role="inner"/>
            <member type="way" ref="42115602" role="inner"/>
            <member type="way" ref="42117265" role="inner"/>
            <member type="way" ref="42125939" role="inner"/>
            <member type="way" ref="52374472" role="outer"/>
            <member type="way" ref="126149886" role="outer"/>
            <member type="way" ref="126149894" role="outer"/>
            <member type="way" ref="52434337" role="outer"/>
            <member type="way" ref="126263156" role="inner"/>
            <tag k="name" v="Moses Lake"/>
            <tag k="natural" v="water"/>
            <tag k="source" v="yahoo_wms"/>
            <tag k="type" v="multipolygon"/>
    </relation>
```

I then checked the DB table definition in geometryc_columns and saw this:

> osm=# select * from geometry_columns where f_table_name like '%water%';
>    f_table_catalog | f_table_schema |      f_table_name       | f_geometry_column | coord_dimension |  srid  |    type
>   -----------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------+------------
>                    | public         | osm_new_waterways       | geometry          |               2 | 900913 | LINESTRING
>                    | public         | osm_new_waterareas      | geometry          |               2 | 900913 | GEOMETRY
>                    | public         | osm_new_waterareas_gen1 | geometry          |               2 | 900913 | GEOMETRY
>                    | public         | osm_new_waterareas_gen0 | geometry          |               2 | 900913 | GEOMETRY

The GEOMETRY type is new to me, but I assume that it is a valid type to store polygons/multi-polygons.

I followed the tutorial at http://imposm.org/docs/imposm/2.5.0/tutorial.html and had no problems with any of the steps listed there, but I'm curious if given the nature of this feature, should I have done something more to enable it to be parsed from the extract and created in the DB?

Many thanks for any clues you can provide.